# How do I bundle a node/php backend within my Ionic app?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

So I want to make a backend for my Ionic app, but I want to use a local database (sqlite), it won't connect with a cloud server or anything like that, so how do I make a backend that'll be kind of "booted" at the same time the app is started?

Or maybe, if I'm in the wrong path to do it, how is it usually made?